# NVIDIA driver can't find physical present gpu

Tags: fedora, drivers, nvidia

Setting:

> I have a Lenovo Y50-70 which has an integrated graphics card:
>
> - Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 4600 (HSW GT2)
>
> and an additional graphics card:
>
> - NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M

a while aggo a windows update broke the usability/detection of the second graphics card (didn't looked to deep into this problem back then...)
since then I installed fedora 35 workstation...
Now I wanted to install the respective (= I double checked -> it is the correct one for the 960M series!) NVIDIA driver to use both graphics card with fedora... (which didn't worked...)

following [error log](https://pastebin.com/M0u9a7yi) was produced...
what I noticed in the error log: the installation script seems to not "find" the nvidia gpu -> is maybe the gpu broken? -> could a simple windows update "physically" break a gpu?

Comment: Maybe try a newer version of the Nvidia drivers? 349.16 was released in 2015, which would have been kernel version 4-ish, fedora 35 ships with 5.15. I hope this helps, but I wouldn't expect this alone to fail card detection.

Comment: before I tryied 349.15 I tried the newest one which resulted into  version error -> 349.15 lists my gpu as suported ones -> thats the reason I have chosen this version

Comment: but... did you ment that this driver version is straight incompatible with my os version? -> but that would mean that this gpu would be incompatible with the newest os(fedora) ?

Comment: What version did you try first? What "version error" did you get? Please post the results of everything you have tried so far.